# Generic insertionSort using a Comparator object as a parameter?

Tags: java, generics, comparator, superclass, insertion-sort

If I'm given this method header:

```
/**
 * This generic method sorts the input array using an insertion sort and the input Comparator object.
 */
public static <T> void insertionSort(T[] array , Comparator<? super T> comparatorObj){

        // Implement method
}
```

For the `Comparator<? super T> comparatorObj` part in the parameter, am I suppose to be making a comparator object method that tells how it should be comparing when it's used in the insertionSort parameter?

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to pass in a `Comparator` object. Essentially, you just need to implement method

```
int compare(T obj1, T obj2)
```

Google some examples, e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
public static <T>
void insertionSortGeneric(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
   for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    /* Insert a[i] into the sorted sublist */
    T v = a[i];
    int j;
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (c.compare(a[j], v) <= 0) break;
        a[j + 1] = a[j];
    }
    a[j + 1] = v; }}
```

Comment: You did not answer OP's question at all.

Comment: use this snippet in your code It will defenitely works just use loop to print a.

Comment: I was asking if I will need to make a Comparator object that tells how to compare the elements in the generic array.

Comment: @ProjectDefy unless you constrain `T` to be intrinsically comparable, i.e. `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> ...`, then yes, you'd need to specify some external means to compare array elements.